# How to change colors on multilines plotting using matplotlib and python?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I am using a dictionary to plot lines with python and matplotlib i can't figure out why the colors of my lines are not changing

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dico =  {'A01': [(u'11/10/12-08:00:01', 2.0), (u'11/10/12-08:10:00', 10.0), \
                 (u'11/10/12-08:20:01', 5.0), (u'11/10/12-08:30:01', 15.0), \
                 (u'11/10/12-08:40:00', 7.0), (u'11/10/12-08:50:01', 45.0)],
         'A02': [(u'11/10/12-08:00:01', 10.0), (u'11/10/12-08:10:00', 12.0), \
                 (u'11/10/12-08:20:01', 15.0), (u'11/10/12-08:30:01', 10.0), \
                 (u'11/10/12-08:40:00', 17.0), (u'11/10/12-08:50:01', 14.0)]}

x = []
y = []
lstPlot = []
plt.gca().set_color_cycle(["b", "g", "r", "c", "m", "y", "k"])
for key, values in dico.iteritems():
    for i in  sorted(values):
        # date sting to date obj
        dateObj = datetime.strptime(i[0], "%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S")
        line = dateObj, i[1]
        lstPlot.append(line)
    for i in sorted(lstPlot):
        x.append(i[0])
        y.append(i[1])
    plt.plot(x, y, label=key)



# plotting

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel("titre")
plt.title("Modbus")
plt.show()
```

Note that I have different colors in the legend but not in the plot.

Answer (score 3):

They *are* changing, but you're overplotting one with the other.  These lines

```
x = []
y = []
lstPlot = []
```

need to be *inside* the loop.  Otherwise `lstPlot` will just grow.  For example, adding `print lstPlot` inside the loop gives:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 0, 1), 10.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 10), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 20, 1), 15.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 30, 1), 10.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 40), 17.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 50, 1), 14.0)]
[(datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 0, 1), 10.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 10), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 20, 1), 15.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 30, 1), 10.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 40), 17.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 50, 1), 14.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 0, 1), 2.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 10), 10.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 20, 1), 5.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 30, 1), 15.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 40), 7.0), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 11, 8, 50, 1), 45.0)]
```

(You'll probably have to scroll over to see that the second list is a lot longer than the first, but you should notice that the first value is the same in both.)

So you can either clear the lists inside, or maybe you can simplify it a bit:

```
for key, values in dico.iteritems():
    points = [(datetime.strptime(i[0], "%d/%m/%y-%H:%M:%S"), i[1]) for i in values]
    points.sort()
    x, y = zip(*points)
    plt.plot(x, y, label=key)
```

That code, with the addition of @bmu's suggestion of

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

to automatically make the x-axis look nice, produces

[image: fixed image]

[Alternatively, you might want to use `get_xticklabels()` and methods like `set_rotation` for finer control.]

Comment: to get better date formatting you could also use `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()`

Comment: @bmu: nice, that *does* make it look a lot better.  I'll edit the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
colors = ["b", "g", "r", "c", "m", "y", "k"]
for (key, values), c in zip(dico.iteritems(), colors):
    ...
    plt.plot(x, y, c, label=key)
```